# Entity Framework duplicate entries in many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have already read many posts about the entity framework problem with many to many and its beeing a pain in the neck again.

Colaborador has an ICollection of Time and
Time has an Icollection of Colaborador

Some people say that it´s necessary to attach the child entity before Add in the context(didn´t work for me, Pk error).

I am using simple injector and my context is per request.

My associative table is mapped like this:

```
            HasMany<Time>(c => c.Times)
            .WithMany(t => t.Colaboradores)
            .Map(ct =>
            {
                ct.MapLeftKey("ColaboradorId");
                ct.MapRightKey("TimeId");
                ct.ToTable("Receptor");
            });
```

It creates the associative table in the database.
When i try to insert a Colaborador(entity), i add in its list some Times(Teams), add to DbContext and then SaveChanges().

When i do this, it creates a new Colaborador, insert correctly in the associative table(the ids) but also duplicate the Time.

```
var colaborador = Mapper.Map<ColaboradorViewModel, Colaborador>(colaboradorVm);
List<TimeViewModel> timesVm = new List<TimeViewModel>();
colaboradorVm.TimesSelecionados.ForEach(t => timesVm.Add(_serviceTime.BuscarPorId(t)));

colaborador.Times = Mapper.Map<ICollection<TimeViewModel>, ICollection<Time>>(timesVm);
```

The function BuscarPorId does the Find method and returns a Time.

I have figured out that if i call the Add command, the entity will mark the child´s state as Added as well, but if i attempt to attach the Time or change it´s state to Unchanged, i get a primary key error...

```
foreach (var item in colaborador.Times)
{                
    lpcContext.Set<Time>().Attach(item);
    //lpcContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

Is there any way of tell to entity framework to not insert a specific child? So only the main and associative table are populated?

Comment: This is not related to many-many relationship. It happens always. If you need to avoid to add related entities you need to retrieve them from the database (same context that you will use for add) or attach them to context then set the EntityState to Unchanged

Comment: @Moho : Attaching an entity of type failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

Comment: @bubi, i retrieve the Time with the Find method, then i add it in the Colaborador´s list. Just before Add in the context i have tried to attach(just like show above) but i got the Pk error.  Isn´t that the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mapper.Map` creates new `Time` objects which are not attached to your context, so you must attach them as `Unmodified`, but attaching them causes another error due to duplicate PK because your context is already tracking the original copies of the `Time` entities.  Using the `Find` method will retrieve these tracked and locally cached entities.

Find and use the entity already attached to your context:

Instead of:

```
colaborador.Times = Mapper.Map<ICollection<TimeViewModel>, ICollection<Time>>(timesVm);
```

Use:

```
var times = new List<Time>();
var dbSet = lpcContext.Set<Time>();

foreach( var t in timesVm )
{
    var time = dbSet.Find( t.Id );

    if( null == time )
    {
        time = Mapper.Map<TimeViewModel, Time>( t );
    }

    times.Add( time );
}

collaborador.Times = times;
```

Comment: Moho, timesVm already have the data i need, but it is in the view model(previosly with _serviceTime.BuscarPorId()... where BuscarPorId does the Find method).
Is it really needful to do an other foreach for each id again? Since in this layer i don't have the access the the DbSet(i call the service to do that for me), but i know they are the same context(because i set them to be per request)

Comment: You already know the answer since your code doesn't work; `Mapper.Map` creates new `Time` objects which are not attached to your context, so you must attach them as `Unmodified`, but attaching them causes another error due to duplicate PK because your context is already tracking the original copies of the `Time` entities.  Using the `Find` method will retrieve these tracked and locally cached entities.

Comment: Finally i have understood how it works and i would like to thank you @Moho.